# Update all fields of table with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command

Tags: wpdb

I write code with `$wpdb->insert` command into the database table `wp_coin_price`. After inserting data in the table, I write code to update all fields with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but it's not updating the fields.

```
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'coin_price', 
    array( 
        'title'     => trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
        'liveprice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
        'changing'  => trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
        'lowest'    => trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        'topest'    => trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
        'time'      => trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue)   
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
)."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    title = VALUES('title' => trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue) ),
    liveprice = VALUES('liveprice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue) ),
    changing = VALUES('changing' => trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue) ),
    lowest = VALUES('lowest' => trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue) ),
    topest = VALUES('topest' => trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue) ),
    time =  VALUES('time' => trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue) )";
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you fix the typo on the line 

`titile = VALUES('title' =>  trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue)     ) ,` ? Seems like it should be `title` instead of `titile`

Comment: I fixing but until not working